# Git hook python script to call executable binary

Tags: python, git, subprocess, githooks, working-directory

The image shows project structure. There is a binary executable (c++ output) which is supposed to be run by post-checkout script, and it fails.

[image]

`post-checkout` is python script

```python
#!/bin/python3

import subprocess

file_path = r'../build/executable.x'
subprocess.check_call([file_path, '-list'], cwd=r'C:/code/MyProject/build')
```

The error that I get when running git checkout command is:

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['../build/executable.x', '-list']' returned non-zero exit status 3221225785.

However if I run this script from windows cmd, it works fine.
To run it in cmd, I go to `.githooks` directory, and then run 'python3 post-checkout'

I am wondering if I miss setting the working directory correctly or it is git script that runs in an expected way in windows machine.

Comment: 3221225785 is 0xC0000139, which is STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND.  Are you mixing Windows and WSL executables here?

Comment: @TimRoberts not sure if I understand your point. The binary executable is compiled by msys gcc (in my windows machine), and I had no issue running it by python script from cmd.

Comment: That says it is a Windows executable.  Is your `git` running in a Windows shell, or are you running `git` in WSL?  If you have a WSL Python, it's going to want to load WSL executables, not Windows executables.

Comment: Probably git is running on Windows shell. `git --version` returns `git version 2.33.0.windows.2`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use backslashes in `file_path` instead of forward?

Comment: no, I tried with one and also double backslash. Still running python from cmd works, and git checkout doesn't work. I get the same error

Comment: Confusing.  If you do `import sys` / `print(sys.version)` in the git-hooks run, what do you get?   You might need to print to a file to see it.

Comment: for both terminal and git checkout I get `3.9.7 (default, Nov 10 2021, 08:28:38)  [GCC 11.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]` when printing `sys.version`, GCC part is confusing though

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the python that run the script. There are two python interpreters available on my machine, one was under `msys` and the other one the standalone python for windows.

It seems the combination of msys python and windows git were not happy about running the binary. I tried windows python and windows git which successfully run the binary by trigger git hook.

I had to specify default python interpreter by flipping the order of env variable path, and bring up windows python to prioritize it.

[image]